# Angular Autcomplete Text Box from API Array

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, mat-autocomplete

I'm trying to figure out how to get a text box to populate with user's emails from an API call to the server.

**select-users.component.html:**

```html
<input type="text"
    placeholder="Email Search"
    aria-label="Email"
    matInput
    [formControl]="myControl"
    [matAutocomplete]="auto">
<mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
  <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions | async" [value]="option">
    {{option}}
  </mat-option>
</mat-autocomplete>
```

**select-users.component.ts**

```js
interface User {
  email: string;
}

export class SelectUsersComponent implements OnInit {
  public userList: User[] = [];
  myControl = new FormControl();
  // options: string[] = ['clark.kent@mail.com', 'james.t.kirk@mail.com', 'joe.shmo@mail.com'];
  options: string[] = [];
  filteredOptions: Observable<string[]>;

  constructor(private gService: GService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.userSearch().then();
    this.filteredOptions = this.myControl.valueChanges.pipe(
      startWith(''),
      map(value => this._filter(value))
    );
  }

  private _filter(value: string): string[]{
    const filterValue = value.toLowerCase();
    return this.options.filter(option => option.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue));
  }

  /**
   * Retrieve users from gService
   */
    public userSearch = async () => {
    const result = await this.gService.getUsers();
    this.userList = [];
    result?.list?.entries?.forEach(({ entry }) => {
      this.userList.push({
        email: entry.properties?.['cm:email']
      });
    });
    this.options = this.userList.map(User => User.email);
  };
}
```

Where the **userSearch** function is making a call to a separate **gService.getUsers()** function that returns an Alfresco-based set of users (this is the API call, which isn't really shown here in the TypeScript code), stores the User objects into the **userList**, and lastly stores all **userList User.email**'s into the **options** array.

Now, my problem is that the **return** function in **_filter** doesn't return anything at all. I've done a series of tests and the **options** array populates just fine and the emails look appropriate in print-outs and logs, but the filter isn't sorting (or is dropping?) that array.

Additional oddity: if you take a look at the **commented-out** version of **options**, if you comment it back in and run the program you actually get results from **_filter** just as you would expect to.

So I'm kind of at a loss - am I storing the emails in the **options** array wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my issue.
As it turned out, the array that was making it into the **options** array had a lot of gaps in it (I'm not sure why, honestly) in so much that it looked like the following:

```
['rich@mail.com', 'poor@mail.com',,,'medium@mail.com',,'middle@mail.com']
```

So just out of curiosity I put some code to filter out the empty space in the array and shorten it to only include filled indexes:

```js
var len = this.options.length;
    var i;
    for(i=0; i<len; i++){
      this.options[i] && this.options.push(this.options[i]);
    }
    this.options.splice(0, len);
```

It's not the cleanest way to do it as its just a simple iterator, but it actually made the program work as intended!

Hopefully this helps someone in the future.